# Can I use mutableStateOf() instead of produceState in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

I don't think the `produceState` is necessary, so I think I can replace Code A with Code B, is it right?

BTW, the Code B can run.

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }

    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
           ...
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    var  uiState by remember {mutableStateOf(DetailsUiState(isLoading = true))}

    val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
    uiState = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
        DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
    } else {
        DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
    }


    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
           ...
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at `productState` under the hood:

```
@Composable
fun <T> produceState(
    initialValue: T,
    @BuilderInference producer: suspend ProduceStateScope<T>.() -> Unit
): State<T> {
    val result = remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        ProduceStateScopeImpl(result, coroutineContext).producer()
    }
    return result
}
```

`productState` without a key in it's arguments, uses `LaunchedEffect` with `Unit` key which Create an effect that matches the lifecycle of the call site.

It means if `DetailsScreen` recomposes, the code that provides `uiState` won't start again.

But In code B, you are just remembering `DetailsUiState` across recomposition, and below line will be executed in every recomposition.

```
val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
uiState = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
    DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
} else {
    DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the code  `uiState.isLoading -> {..}` in Code B maybe will never be launched?

Comment: No I mean if `viewModel.cityDetails` is doing some expensive operation (api call for example) it will be execute in every recompositions

Comment: I have tested the Code B,  `uiState.isLoading -> {..}` is not be launched.

Comment: I think the app will be blocked if `viewModel.cityDetails` is doing some expensive operation in Code B, right?